# SQL Server cannot run on dockerfile (Codeigniter 3)

Tags: sql-server, docker, codeigniter

I had a problem when running the dockerfile, when I built the image there was a warning message "Unable to locate package msodbcsql17".

here is my dockerfile:

```
# Use an official PHP runtime as a parent image
FROM php:7.4-apache

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libonig-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        unixodbc-dev \
        gnupg2 \
        && docker-php-ext-install mbstring xml pdo pdo_mysql \
        && apt-get clean \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Microsoft SQL Server Prerequisites
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools \
    && echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc \
    && /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc" \
    && apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev \
    && pecl install pdo_sqlsrv sqlsrv \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_sqlsrv sqlsrv

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /var/www/html/
COPY . /var/www/html/

# Grant permissions for the Apache web server to access the application
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && a2enmod rewrite

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Start Apache server
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

I have tried many ways but have not succeeded. what is the correct code like?

Comment: Have you started by looking at the output of `docker run -it --rm php:7.4-apache cat /etc/os-release`? i.e.: You can't install Debian 10 packages onto Debian 11 distros. Are you also in the habit of ignoring warnings output from `apt-key add -` and `apt-get`? The `apt-key` tool has been deprecated since Debian 9 days and its continued use can cause signature check failures during package installs.

Comment: Is sql image downloaded properly. Delete the image and run the pull command again `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest` to download the image.